# The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors. 502.3 - Bad Gateway: Forwarder Connection Error (ARR) on Azure ASP.NET Core App

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-502

All of a sudden we are seeing this random error / exception in our web application.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway).

In the Log Stream, we are seeing the following details, with specific error code as 502.3 - Bad Gateway: Forwarder Connection Error (ARR).

Also, sometimes in the browser itself we see "The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors." getting displayed.

Most of the searches for these error codes refer to "IIS / Proxy Server" configuration. But, we haven't changed any such settings.

The error happens very randomly and not specific to any user action/function. Same functionality works first and on second execution immediately after first one throws this error.

How to figure out what is causing this and how to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I google this question, because the program was normal at the beginning, and the subsequent 502.3 error. After I checked the information on the Internet, I feel that it can only give us an inspiration, and it cannot solve your problem immediately.

So my suggestion is that first you browse  [post1](https://forums.iis.net/t/1179106.aspx) and [post2](https://forums.iis.net/t/1176851.aspx)  I provided.

Next, proceed to Troubleshoot according to the steps of the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-cache-items-arr-v2). Specific errors require specific analysis.